# Change JSP from Javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsp, spring-mvc

I set my css style inside jsp file. I added two "a link" and now i want to change **spring:theme** by any jQuery method from other file (js script).

**Question:** How to write function onClick() for my "a link" to change this **spring:theme** from different file?

**JSP file**

```
<head>
<c:choose>
<c:when test="">
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
    <spring:theme code="standard.default.css.file" var="defaultCssFile" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
        href="<c:url value="${defaultCssFile}" />" />
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
</head>



<div id="changeWrapper">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="change ch1" data-change2="firstCSS">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="change ch2" data-change2="secondCSS">b</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add id to your `<link>` tag like the following:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" id="myId"
    href="<c:url value="${defaultCssFile}" />" />
```

By using the `id` attribute we can change the css file of the `<link>` dynamically.

Try the following:

```
$('#changeWrapper').on('click', '.change', function() {
    var obj = $(this), cssfile = obj.data('change2');
    $('#myId').attr('href', cssfile);
});
```

Comment: Is any way to addClass() with new css to body (in this case) instead changing one css to second one ? Because in my second css file i change only color and font parameters...

Comment: @JacobRutka we can css rules at runtime, check [Add Rules](http://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets).